# How can I determine the codepage of the selected keyboard language in Win10?

Tags: delphi, winapi

I need for some reason the codepage of the language set by the currently selected keyboard layout in the current process. (I use Win10 with per app language settings)

`getThreadLocale` does not change when UI language changes. It gives back the default locale of the process.

`getProcessInformation`/`getThreadInformation` does not contain any information about the current language/locale.

I think the chain of the needed information is:

selected language => matching locale => codepage

if I have the current locale id (matching to the selected language) then I can fetch its codepage by:

`getLocaleInfoW( idLocale, LOCALE_IDEFAULTANSICODEPAGE, buff, buffSize );`

Is(Are) there any winapi call(s) to get the information described above?

Comment: And, what if the target thread/process is using a locale in a library (ie, the C runtime library) that is not tied to the OS to being with? What exactly are you trying to accomplish? This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/).

Comment: @RemyLebeau I need this information just in the main thread.

Comment: but you have not explained WHY you need this info, or WHAT you intend to do with it. There may be other solutions available to accomplish your goal, whatever that may be.

Comment: I don't understand what "currently selected UI language associated to the active process" means. It seems very application-specific. Perhaps your app is not setting the thread locale value. On Windows and modern Delphi, everything is UTF-16 so languages are not about codepage and string encoding.

Comment: Is [this](https://superuser.com/questions/766400/make-language-change-specific-to-window-app-not-whole-system-windows-8-1/1348350#1348350) what you're referring to?

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez For legacy applications that do not support unicode, including anything built in D2007 or older, Windows will automatically assign a codepage based on the operating system locale to interpret the ANSI text.  Running a Japanese ANSI program on a US Windows installation, for example, will display all menus and fonts incorrectly as it would be trying to interpret something like Shift-JIS as 1252.  I think this is what OP is getting at - trying to determine what codepage that windows is currently using for the application to interpret ANSI text.

Comment: @Olivier yes, it is. and i need the code page of the selected keyboard language

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez the codepage associated with the currently selected keyboard layout

Comment: @J... I assumed the OP was using Delphi 2009+ Unicode version. He should give more information.

Comment: So perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/a/19321020/458259 would help to retrieve the current keyboard layout. A simple search on SO helps.

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez I need the code page not because the app but the ansi encoded files read/write by the app. i use D10.3.3.

Comment: Your request is *really* confusing. It does not make much sense to use ansi encoded files in this case - use UTF-8. Or at least, use the system Ansi codepage. And this system code page (used for ANSI APIs, and for Delphi AnsiString variable) *does not change when you change the keyboard language*: you need to change the whole system settings, then restart Windows. You lost me.

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez "use utf-8" : say it (for example) to MicroSoft to change RTF file encoding to utf-8 instead of ansi.

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez I cant use just the system code page. when i switch between languages i use national dependent characters does not exist in for example in 1252 (western european). so i have to use the codepage of the special characters when i write the files.

Comment: This whole idea of changing the code page per file is a bad idea. Use UTF-8 then your file will be compatible with any kind of code page and language characters. For RTF you just use \utf8 in the file header IIRC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `TLabel` caption sets to the `CodePage` associated with the current keyboard language by the `TButton`.`OnClick` event handler.

```
unit Unit3;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm3 = class(TForm)
    Label1: TLabel;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form3: TForm3;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  tid : word;
  lid : word;
  ndxLocale, buffSize : integer;
  localeName : string;
  buff : pchar;
begin
  tid := getCurrentThreadID;
  lid := getKeyboardLayout( tid );
  ndxLocale := languages.IndexOf( lid );
  localeName := languages.LocaleName[ndxLocale];
  buffSize := getLocaleInfoEx( pchar( localeName ), LOCALE_IDEFAULTANSICODEPAGE, NIL, 0 );
  getMem( buff, buffSize*sizeOf(char) );
  try
    getLocaleInfoEx( pchar( localeName ), LOCALE_IDEFAULTANSICODEPAGE, buff, buffSize );
    label1.caption := strPas( buff );
  finally
    freeMem( buff );
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

GetACP() returns "ansi" code page...lol, not really ansi, but that's what windows calls it. Can also use GetCPInfo() to get additional information after you call GetACP(). Things get trickier for Japanese, Chinese, and other far east languages that use double byte character set. I still work on an application that is MBCS. Would be nice if we could convert to Unicode, but it's not happening and it won't be my problem soon.

Comment: unfortunatelly it gives back a constant value associated to the app. i need a changing value depending on the current keyboard language

Comment: GetACP is for the ANSI API version - before Delphi 2009. It is not what the OP searches for: the keyboard layout. You can change the keyboard layout, but it won't change the system codepage for legacy app.